# Change a tag's href

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I'm making an userscript for [Instagram](https://instagram.com/).
What I want to do is to change an `<a>` tag's href. This tag doesn't have any ID/class.[image]

I already found how to select it:

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".oJZym").getElementsByTagName("a");
x[0]
```

I want it to open a new tab to https://instagram.com/nukl3ar_p/ .
I've already tried:

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".oJZym").getElementsByTagName("a");
x[0].href = "https://instagram.com";
```

or

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".oJZym").getElementsByTagName("a");
x[0].onclick = window.open("https://instagram.com/nukl3ar_p/", "_blank");
```

But it keeps redirecting me without even having clicked it. How to fix?

Comment: You've to wrap the action in a function and prevent the default action of the link: `x[0].onclick = function (e) {e.preventDefault(); window.open(...);};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when the page gets hoisted, your code gets executed. so they are redirecting here. You need to use preventDefault to stop that.

```
x[0].onclick = function(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      window.open("https://instagram.com/nukl3ar_p/", "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use CSS Selector `>` to get the child `<a>` then set href.

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".oJZym>a");
x.href = "https://instagram.com/nukl3ar_p/";
x.target ='_blank';
```

```html
<div  class="oJZym" ><a href="/">Test</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the d3 library to modify it like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7"></script>
<script>

const div = d3.select(".oJZym").select("a")
              .attr("href","https://instagram.com/nukl3ar_p/")
              .attr("target","_blank");

</script>
```

This script will use the d3 library to select the hyperlink within the ".oJZym" class and set its href and target attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try these line..

```
var x = document.querySelector("oJZym + a")
x[0].href = "https://instagram.com";
```

Comment: ```querySelector('.oJZym > a')```, it won't work the way you set it.

Comment: This will not work. `x` is not an array. You are trying to set the `href` property of `undefined`.

Comment: dont use . use only  'oJZym > a'

Comment: You need to specify the ```.``` in ```querySelector```. Also ```+``` will select sibling and not child. Maybe you should have tested it?

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = document.querySelector("oJZym a")
x[0].href = "https://instagram.com";
```

Comment: As far i'm aware is the querySelector in the way you write it like that not working. It will now look for oJZym with a in the same element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).